# How to disable tapping on selectedRows?

Tags: swift

I need to choose a currencyPair which has real-time conversion rate prices. When I try to add a new pair, I select the firstCurrency, and if the secondCurrency was already selected, it shouldn't allow interaction. For that, I compare the currencyPair with the savedPairs, and if the currency isEnabled = true, the user can select. I managed to find out the currencies which can't be selected, but when I call the function on didSelectRow and change the correspondent currencies to isEnabled = false, it switch them to false on DidSelectRow, but on TableViewCell the currencies are still nil.

Also, I managed to make it work using a different approach with cellForRow, however, every time that I scroll it changes the selected cells.

Any idea on how to fix these issues?

Thanks a lot.

```
  func getCorrespondingCurrencies(for selectedCurrency: Currency, in currencyPairs: [CurrencyPair]?) -> [Currency] {
        var selectedCurrencies = [Currency]()

        if let currencyPairs = currencyPairs {
            for var currencyPair in currencyPairs {
                if currencyPair.firstCurrency.currencyCode == selectedCurrency.currencyCode {
                    selectedCurrencies.append(currencyPair.secondCurrency)
                    currencyPair.secondCurrency.isEnabled = false
                    print(currencyPair.secondCurrency,"secondCurrency")
                }

            }

        }
        return selectedCurrencies
    }
```

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AddCurrencyTableViewCell

        if isFirstCurrencyScreen {
            if let cellCurrency = cell.currency{
                let addCurrencyTVC = UIStoryboard.addCurrencyTVC
                addCurrencyTVC.delegate = self.delegate
                AddCurrencyViewController.firstCurrency = cell.currency
                navigationController?.pushViewController(addCurrencyTVC, animated: true)
                if let savedCurrencies = UserDefaultsManager.shared.currencies {
                    currencyViewModel.getCorrespondingCurrencies(for: cellCurrency, in: savedCurrencies)
                }
                return
            }
        }
        let currencyPair = CurrencyPair(from:  AddCurrencyViewController.firstCurrency!, to: cell.currency!)
        UserDefaultsManager.shared.currencies?.append(currencyPair)
        delegate?.addCurrencyPair(currencyPair)
        dismiss(animated: true) {}

    }
```

```
  func configure(currency: Currency?) {
        guard let currency = currency else { return }

        currencyNameLabel.text = currency.name
        symbolLabel.text = currency.currencyCode
        if let imageName = currency.imageName, let image = UIImage(named: imageName) {
            flagImageView.image = image
            flagImageView.image = image
        } else {
            flagImageView.image = ImageData.getImage(for: .flagPlaceholder)
        }
        flagImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        if currency.isEnabled == false {
            setDisabledMode()
        }
    }

    func setDisabledMode() {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        currencyNameLabel.alpha = 0.5
        symbolLabel.alpha = 0.5
    }
```

Comment: Any specific reason your deselecting a selected cell in `didSelectRowAt`?

Comment: To avoid duplicate pairs in the MainTableViewController. In the AddTableViewController, the user select let's say Euro, and in the second Dollar. If the user tries to add a new pair, he can't add Euro-Dollar anymore, so when he selects Euro again, Dollar can't be selected, but he could select Pounds for instance.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you are displaying multiple pairs of currencies and a currency shouldn't be present in more than one pair? Why don't you allow multiple selection and track the indexPaths that are selected instead?

Comment: Actually, a currency can appear in more than one pair, EURUSD and EURGBP, for example, but a pair can't appear more than once, let's say EURUSD and EURUSD. I thought about this but can't do that because I have to show different screens for both currency selections, when you first select, for example, EUR(Screen One), and then USD(Screen two), so in the Main screen(Screen 3) I will have EURUSD.